# Getting all formats of clipboard data in Windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, clipboard

in the below code, I could output text data stored in the clipboard.

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE h;

    if (!OpenClipboard(NULL))
        std::cout << "Can't open clipboard";

    h = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);

    printf("%s\n", (char*)h);

    CloseClipboard();
    return 0;
}
```

How do I get the data if it is a image that is copied in the clipboard?

I tried using CF_UNICODETEXT but i am getting null if the contents of the clipboard is a image.

Basically I want to output whatever that is stored in the clipboard regardless of the format. Is it possible? Or I have to do it individually?

Comment: You are supposed to specifically ask for the formats your program understands. If your program understands text and images, then you ask for text, and you ask for images.

Comment: You may be looking for [`EnumClipboardFormats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumclipboardformats)